# Prove that matrices of determinant 1 can be written as product of (presumably) elementary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

The exercise begins with constructing a linear mapping $T_{ij}(c):\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $i\ne j$ and for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have that $T_{ij}(c)(x)_i=x_i+cx_j$ and $T_{ij}(c)(x)_k=x_k$ otherwise. I am then asked to:

a) Construct a compact set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that its boundary is a proper subset and its image under $T_{ij}(c)$ is congruent to itself

b) Prove that every matrix with determinant $1$ is a product of operators of the form $T_{ij}(c)$

First of, am I correct to assume that $T_{ij}(c)$ is the sum of the identity matrix and a matrix with exactly one non-zero value that is not on the diagonal? Because in that case, a) seems rather trivial (just construct a large enough set where for every point, the j-th coordinate is $0$) and I don't see how b) could be true for an even permutation matrix, for example, since the diagonal entries would have to change.

Comment: For (b), consider the product of $T_{ij}(c)$ and $T_{ji}(c')$. This changes some diagonal entries.

Comment: Thanks! I must have missed that.

Comment: Also, while I don't see how to solve (a), your solution doesn't work; for a set that lies on the plane $x_j=0$, the boundary of the set will be the whole set.

Comment: Can you recall what *congruent to itself* means?

Comment: Maybe I should have worded that differently. The image of A has to be congruent to A, meaning the image of an isometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding question b**

The set of matrices with determinant equal to one is a group called the [special linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_group?wprov=sfti1) $\mathrm{SL}(n, \mathbb R)$. The matrices $T_{ij}(c)$ are matrices of [transvections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping?wprov=sfti1). It is a classical result that the transvections generate the real special linear group. See this [article](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272332/1-s2.0-S0021869386X80016/1-s2.0-0021869386900414/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEAUaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIAncHg%2BaHUHtnQ0N62%2FMTazrWZx8vj7eIQYFcdmep7yUAiEAnf3DY7Q24vz2AuC%2BvEhonvOkzqM7U6B%2B9WzZ0927M%2BgqvQMI7v%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDOeBsyGZ54aP%2BIoBmCqRA7tD3XExA4OUsJe02sPA14EunzXvWp%2F3WHSSJz5gi1j71kDdICo4ffNO5hF9rT7%2BDSsnSsWA303tRkoZtPrnFjCH%2BqMFdB7oj1%2FANs4dseB8990nGUlSper6yGCLd7H%2BQDVUFq08TKd0rQg6Pk2TZtzvC0uCtBBz3e5S%2BzuVtiCtwOfbonRGi4WQLpxl4Tr5Vn3IRwUqcI7CDVxvULHSio8f8Bsw6CrfXebtQ71y4JdzfpcHLiYaTLCQ1uC3ncTAyHEriXP%2FWEjOTd71h62qU9SDBV%2B7pgn%2BSawc08%2FeVkoBFM%2Fyb50qSf2kdCJXyVPCfIpPX6X6%2BuiaiAttPzrMDMMzUx6g8rty5zO0GU4UKfl4x8KHv4388sbA3RKQI%2FDDku2sc3k6rIZHFMhrg33pn9aeB%2BX3zA2Bu2ZpX3HevAn0OUfZVfb4XZtHmlERmwNq9cq4sVdon2kps6iqhKRuzZ%2BWmI939v%2B%2BmbzY%2FSYgav2lgDxUBjI7UH4PKsZUG%2BKXgY1BKEaIEk8R4uP3Zi9p%2B7IfMMrUnvoFOusBvTFFli51wKNoPpwEd5Se6SXu4OSUwpD3MeYuQM4gRWTc0Rt9LkBfzyQTz5IpL1YS%2FAAUNQ5RO1G8rVXRVKAZCtk7f%2BK2IOXGffli9RmkNp%2BBVImMICTa%2F78uUscqM%2F2%2BpEbiwPHAz62KB5Cw2JlS3b%2B0ZECE0QF4kj66IX4ZsGcbbWvPleSsACV39nn4xh2jkQxv%2FaB86LnOos%2Fj1ZREh4SThV7IH5ub8cmMnUcTHb602m6bElfWw9n7joC7kvprGdPc6cOp6E%2BXXymUBz2wSBLy5riZEk095WG%2BZIgQLbPAGAnMw%2FqENghOMQ%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200827T131856Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY3G65PNHV%2F20200827%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=67d003d3b122a704b6f56317ba97d0d482a4663bed10ca74181400fc85b5a115&hash=85a28795d2d4ee30deb812f39ca636fa0ec01e1fa508773e9ea40b4482f938ce&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0021869386900414&tid=spdf-af0b41f2-10f3-49fe-8eb7-f5870dd30560&sid=f07f211a6da26945843b166094c0149f5c0cgxrqb&type=client) for a proof (or Artin’s book Geometric algebra).

If you want to find a proof by yourself, take any matrix $A$ and look at what $A T_{ij}(c)$ and $T_{ij}(c)A$ are. Then proceed with a proof by induction.

**Regarding question a**

See the answer from [GReyes](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/633848/greyes) to the question [Ellipse congruent to its image under a shear map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805100/ellipse-congruent-to-its-image-under-a-shear-map) that I posted. It should inspire you to find a solution to question a!