# Ellipse congruent to its image under a shear map

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, conic-sections

Consider the real plane $\mathbb R^2$ and the [shear mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping)
$$T(c) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
c & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Is it possible to find an ellipse $E \equiv \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{x^2}{b^2} =1$ whose image under $T_c$ is congruent to itself (the image of itself under an isometry)?

I know that the image of $E$ under $T_c$ is the subset having for equation

$$\frac{X^2}{a^2} + \frac{(Y-cX)^2}{b^2} =1$$

but I'm not able to select appropriate $a,b$ (depending on $c$) to get the conclusion or a contradiction.

The question is a subsequent question of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805024/prove-that-matrices-of-determinant-1-can-be-written-as-product-of-presumably-e).

Comment: if $c=0$ you will have congruence

Comment: @guy3141 I agree with this. The case $c \neq 0$ is the one of interest through!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Take an ellipse passing through the points $A(0,1)$, $B(0,-1)$, $C(1,-c/2)$ and $D(-1,c/2)$, centered at the origin and with tangents at $C$ and $D$ being vertical.Your shear takes the given points to $T(A)=(0,1)$, $T(B)=(0,-1)$, $T(C)=(1,c/2)$ and $T(D)=(-1,-c/2)$ and your original ellipse to its mirror image about the $x$-axis. It is not possible to find an ellipse of the form you propose whose image is congruent to itself. You need a "rotated" one like the one I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Indeed, I discovered after posting the question that it is not possible to find a solution with an ellipse of the form I posted.